# Access Vue from external files

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, commonjs, vue-router

I would like to define my routes in an external file for readability.

My `main.js` file is where I initiate my Vue app. Seen below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App'

vue.use(VueRouter)

// I would like these route definitions to be contained in their own file
var Monday = Vue.extend({ template: '<div>Monday view<div>' })
var Tuesday = Vue.extend({ template: '<div>Tuesday view<div>' })
...

var router = new VueRouter()

router.map({
  '/monday': { component: Monday },
  '/tuesday': { component: Tuesday }

router.start(App, 'body)
```

I would prefer to separate the route definitions `var Monday = Vue.extend({ ... })` etc, into their own files for readability when the application scales.

The problem: if I was to create a `RouteDefinitions.js` file, I don't have access to "Vue", which I need to define `Vue.extend`. Should I `import Vue from 'vue'` **again** from inside RouteDefinitions.js? Is this a red flag? Or should I simply keep all my route logic inside main.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it. In your `main.js` do something like this

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import router from './config/router'

Vue.router = router

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Then in the `router.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [ 
    /* your routes definition here */ 
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((route, redirect, next) => {
  /* your route hooks */
  next()
})

router.afterEach(function (transition) {
  /* your route hooks */
})

export default router
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I'm using a pre-v2.0 vue-router. To folks looking at this in the future, some of the options passed to VueRouter({}) won't work for us. You may want to simply give the VueRouter function to the router variable `const router = new VueRouter()`. Otherwise this worked like a charm! Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah you are right. My example is based on vue-router 2.0 but you basically get the idea how to move router setup into a separate `.js` module which can be imported in your `main.js`...